# How can we read the data from csv file using java, where a cell contains data with commas?

Tags: java, csv

Example:

[image]

How can I get the first cell value?

Comment: Use a CSV reading library.

Comment: is "heelloe,goil" wrapped in quotes?

Comment: Reopened. This question is not a request for a CSV API, although the answer might be.

Comment: @holtc no its not wrapped with quotes

Comment: then it's not a properly formatted csv, as @EJP has said

Comment: @holtc I tried even having those strings within quotes, but no luck.

Comment: 'No luck' is not a problem description.

Answer (score 0):

If the cell with the internal comma isn't enclosed in quotes, it has been improperly *written*, and you can't read the file properly at all.

You don't really need a CSV library for this: it 's easy enough to write a CSV reader, but you have to know the convention. Any cell can be enclosed in quotes, which take priority over any internal commas, and which should be removed.